# String value cannot be  or empty

Tags: java

for this program encode value that cannot be  or empty, I'm getting this message "final field encode may not have been initialized constructor". Im not sure where to change in program

```
public class Code {
   private final char cha;
   private final String encode ;
   public Code(char cha, String encode ) {
      try {
       
      int x = cha;
      if(x < 50|| x > 100)
         throw new Exception();
      else {
          this.cha= cha;
          this.encode = encode;
      }
      }
      catch(Exception e) {
          System.out.println(e + " Out-of-range Character: "+ cha  +"encode"+ encode +" is wrong");
      }
   }
   public final char getcha() {return cha;}
    
   public final String getencode () {return encode;}

   }
```

Comment: What will `this.encode` be set to if `x < 50 || x > 100`? If you go down that code path it is not assigned a value.

Comment: NEVER throw Exception (as it catches RuntimeExceptions that should be handled differently), and especially NEVER EVER catch Exception (though sometimes you want to catch RuntimeException or Throwable)

Answer (score 1):

The way you've structured your code, if `x` is out of range, then your code will throw an exception but then also immediately catch it. You've just written a weird, inefficient take on this code, which acts *identical* to yours:

```
int x = cha;
if(x < 50|| x > 100) {
  System.out.println(e + " Out-of-range Character: "+ cha  +"encode"+ encode +" is wrong");
} else {
  this.cha= cha;
  this.encode = encode;
}
```

And this shows the problem: In that exceptional code path, you just.. print some stuff and keep right on going. The constructor returns normally.. with `cha` and `encode` not set at all, which is what the compiler error is complaining about: You can't leave a final variable unset like this.

The intent should be obvious: When a precondition isn't met (here, when `x` is out of range), **continuing with the code is obviously wrong, so don't**. You should throw an exception and NOT catch it. Given that this problem is likely 'programmer error' and not 'user error' it should be unchecked. Here's what to do:

```
public Code(char cha, String encode) {
  if (cha < 50 || cha > 100) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Out of range character: " + cha + " encode " + encode);

  this.cha = cha;
  this.encode = encode;
}
```

It's simple, clean, compiles fine, and does exactly what you want. If someone attempts to make a new Code object with an out-of-range character, they can't - they end up with no object and the `new Code()` statement throws an exception instead, which explains precisely what went wrong.

IllegalArgumentException is a baked-in exception that is meant to be used when parameters don't adhere to specified preconditions which applies perfectly to this situation.

It doesn't run into this compiler issue because `throw ...;` statements *end the method* (unless you catch them in the same method, which your code does, and seems rather pointless) and as no actual instance is returned, obviates the need to initialize all `final` fields. The difference is - your code throws an exception but doesn't exit via that route (as you catch it - making the exercise a bit pointless).

Comment: Yes. Your code does not throw any exceptions (because it catches what it throws immediately). My code (that last snippets) does _exactly_ what you just described.